# Import data from ICS file to Google Calender

Tags: api, events, composer-php, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am generating ICS file dynamically and I want to import data from generated ICS file to Google event calendar every day using cron.

I tried to understand Calender API documentation, but no luck!! I don't understand how to configure composer and all that.

It would be very appreciated if someone can guide me easy way!!

Comment: Please show us at least something you have tried. People are reluctant to do other's job.

Answer (score 0):

Read your ICS file. Create a simple project in any language you are familiar with, incorporate Google Calendar V3 api in your project.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet, here you can get sample code.

I think this will help. Please read the sample and documentation before implementing.

Comment: I followed steps given in above link. I created client_secret.json file, uploaded library using composer.json and created quickstart.php file. Now when I enter command as given in step 4, it gives me error of Invalid client secret JSON file. Please note that I am trying to create demo in local xampp server as I don't know how to install composer on live server.